# Google Maps Api vs Browser with Url?

Tags: android, google-maps

Would it be bad practice to use a `WebView` to open up Google maps within an application and do a search for a type of place within a radius of the end user instead of using a Google maps fragment and using their api? I am more comfortable using WebViews as opposed to using the Google maps api. Should i just man up and use the api or just use what i know?

Comment: You answered your own question. Yes you should just man up and use the API. It will give far better results and help you in the future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both will work. On high-end phones with high-speed connections, it will be nearly the same.

Under less than ideal conditions, the `WebView` alternative will take longer to load, longer to respond, and feel sloppy.

I strongly recommend you take the time to implement the `Fragment` alternative.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm also a big fan of your username.

Comment: I don't agree that the WebView alternative will be nearly the same. HTML still sucks on mobile (at least as of today, 2/12/2014)